# How to make my navbar sticky in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my navbar sticky, it is working on a regular screen view but it is not working on mobile view.

I have created a regular navbar for widescreen and a hamburger style navbar on mobile view.

I am still learning and new to frontend so I am aware that the below code is pretty bad. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

var navbar_mobile = document.getElementById("menuToggle");
var sticky_mobile = navbar_mobile.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    navbar_mobile.classList.add("sticky_mobile");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    navbar_mobile.classList.remove("sticky_mobile");
  }
}
```

```css
/* NAVIGATION FOR WIDE SCREEN*/
#navbar {
   z-index: 10;
}
ul li:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.navigation-menu-sep {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a,
.navigation-menu-sep ul li a:after,
.navigation-menu-sep ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.navigation-menu .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}


/* stroke */
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a{
  position: relative;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #0e2e39;
  height: 2px;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}

.sticky_mobile {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #navbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
/* NAVIGATION MENU FOR MOBILE - HAMBURGER STYLE */
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
    #menuToggle {
        display: none;
    }
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<nav class="navigation-menu-sep">
    <ul class="navigation-menu-sep-ul">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-us">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#new-product">New Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#about-us"><li>About us</li></a>
      <a href="#new-product"><li>New Products</li></a>
      <a href="#more"><li>More</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Basically, I have more elements above this navbar.

I am not sure what I did wrong, but the sticky-navbar on mobile view sticks at the top instead of only sticking when the user scrolls.

Comment: code is posted here not somewhere else @DCR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in my javascript, that was the cause of it not being able to add the new class "sticky".
This is not the best but it works.

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
   myFunction();
   myFunction_mobile();
}

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

var navbar_mobile = document.getElementById("menuToggle");
var sticky_mobile = navbar_mobile.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
function myFunction_mobile() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky_mobile) {
    navbar_mobile.classList.add("sticky_mobile");
  } else {
    navbar_mobile.classList.remove("sticky_mobile");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS feature for this.

```
position: sticky;
```

Comment: There are more div elements above the navbar, so `position: sticky;` won't work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
Check the demo, i dont think elements above will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a little buffer before switching to the sticky mode. In the modified example below there is 100px buffer before triggering the sticky mode. Also removed the `sticky_mobile` class as they were both doing the same thing.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop + 100;

var navbar_mobile = document.getElementById("menuToggle");
var sticky_mobile = navbar_mobile.offsetTop + 100;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* NAVIGATION FOR WIDE SCREEN*/
#navbar {
   z-index: 10;
}
ul li:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.navigation-menu-sep {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a,
.navigation-menu-sep ul li a:after,
.navigation-menu-sep ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.navigation-menu .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}


/* stroke */
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a{
  position: relative;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #0e2e39;
  height: 2px;
}
.navigation-menu-sep .navigation-menu-sep-ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #navbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
/* NAVIGATION MENU FOR MOBILE - HAMBURGER STYLE */
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
    #menuToggle {
        display: none;
    }
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">

<nav class="navigation-menu-sep">
    <ul class="navigation-menu-sep-ul">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-us">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#new-product">New Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>

a
<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
b
<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
c
<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
d
<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
e
<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
f


<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#about-us"><li>About us</li></a>
      <a href="#new-product"><li>New Products</li></a>
      <a href="#more"><li>More</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```